# Would a question about RC cars be a valid question for this site?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

**Main Question:**
I know that this Stack Exchange website is for Drones and Model Aircraft, but would a question about RC cars be a valid question (i.e. on-topic/in scope) here?

**Other Questions:**

- Is there already a Stack Exchange website for RC cars? I looked but couldn't find one...
  Just in case, I posted a new [discussion on Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32544/new-rc-vehicle-stack-exchange-website), if you think that it would be a helpful site, please vote it up and comment on it and/or post more ideas for it...
- Is there any Stack Exchange websites that include RC cars in the containing data group?
- Is there any way that we can modify this site to include all RC vehicles instead of just Drones and Aircraft?

Thanks!

Comment: Aside from that, we've had questions that are related to common technologies between all RC fields, but nothing explicitly car-related. But we should really continue this discussion on the Meta site.

Comment: @ifconfig IIRC, new users cannot participate on meta sites until they have +5 rep.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Ah, you're correct! Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't remember that fact. He now does :)

Comment: So what exactly does this all mean?
Can I ask my question about an RC car? Or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @JacobHornbeck If the question pertains mostly to electronic components of an RC car, like the esc, motor, radio system, etc. it should be fine for this site.

Answer (score 7):

I would say yes.

Many of the technologies are similar, so there is likely to be a lot of overlap in knowledge - Motors, Batteries, Engines, Servos, Radio Equipment, etc. - and experience elsewhere has shown me that often the solution to a problem can come from a slightly tangential source; I'm sure there are issues drone users have that RC car users have solved, and vice-versa.

Just note that, at least to start with, the community is quite aircraft focussed so don't be disappointed if answers are initially slow to arrive!

Comment: Additionally this forum is small and not really growing. We could easily handle a few more questions.